# VueJS load component that didn't exist at build time

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am designing an app that will have custom modules that a user can upload and enable at run time. From vue's point of view this module will be a file called config.vue that I want to store on disk and then load it in real time, perhaps using `app.component()`

Will this work at run time in production without a rebuild of the application?